# how to override Serialize method for list of object in BsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have some document saved with different schema in MongoDB one like this:

```
{
    ...
    phones: 
    {
        0: {number:"123"},
        1: {number:"456"}
    }
    ...
}
```

and other like this:

```
{
    ...
    phones: 
        [
            {number:"123"},
            {number:"456"}
        ]
    ...
}
```

one saved data as list of documents in another document and one schema saved list of documents in an array object.

after some search i found this solution and tried to handle different schemas by using BsonSerializer anotation and overriding Deserialize method like this:

```
public class Order
{
    ...
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(FixingPhonesObjectSerialaizer))]
    public List<Phone> phones { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
public override List<Phone?> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Document)
            {
                List<Phone?> phones = new List<Phone?>();

                var bsonReader = context.Reader;
                bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();

                IDiscriminatorConvention valueDiscriminatorConvention = BsonSerializer.LookupDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(object));

                while (bsonReader.ReadBsonType() != BsonType.EndOfDocument)
                {
                    string key = bsonReader.ReadName();
                    Type valueType = valueDiscriminatorConvention.GetActualType(bsonReader, typeof(object));
                    IBsonSerializer valueSerializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(valueType);
                    object value = valueSerializer.Deserialize(context);

                    phones.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Phone>(value.ToBsonDocument()));
                }
                bsonReader.ReadEndDocument();

                return phones;
            }

            return base.Deserialize(context, args);
        }

        protected override void AddItem(object accumulator, object item)
        {
            ((List<Phone?>)accumulator).Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Phone>(item.ToBsonDocument()));
        }

        protected override object CreateAccumulator()
        {
            return new List<Phone?>();
        }

        protected override IEnumerable EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(List<Phone?> value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        protected override List<Phone> FinalizeResult(object accumulator)
        {
            return (List<Phone?>)accumulator;
        }
    }
```

The problem gone and documents deserialize without any problem but when i want to insert objects to DB i got some error to Serialize

> An error occurred while serializing the phones property of class App.Models.Order: Type App.Models.Phone is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.

now i tried to override Serialize method like this but don't what should i write at method body do work correct:

```
public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, List<Phone> value)
        {
            base.Serialize(context, args, value);
        }
```

Do you know any better way to handle different schemas or how should jump this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for `FixingPhonesObjectSerialaizer`? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun i did it, overrided `Deserialize` method is all of code in FixingPhonesObjectSerialaizer class.